# Time complexity - Why is inner loop: for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++) = O(N²))

Tags: time-complexity

I have the following nested for loop:

```
void function(int[] array) {
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
      System.out.println(array[i] + "," + array[j]);
    }
  }
}
```

I understand that nested for loops are usually O(N²), but I don't understand why that is in this case. The inner loop does not iterate through all pairs, but roughly half of the pairs, which seems to be closer to O(log n). Is the time complexity for the inner for loop O(log N), but the time complexity for the entire code becomes O(N²), because the time complexity for the outer loop is more dominant?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, in this loop there are approximately `N*N/2` iteration, less than N^2. But fact is that limit for N->INF of  `N*N/2` is infinite of order 2. That's why complexity is O (N^2)

Comment: (I hope my explanation is clear. I'm not fluent in mathematical English...)

Answer (score 2):

The number of times `println()` is called is N + ... + 2 + 1, where N is the length of the array.

We can [rewrite this sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) as (N (N + 1)) / 2 = (N^2 / 2) + (N / 2).

So, the algorithm's time complexity is in O((N^2 / 2) + (N / 2)).

According to the [properties of the O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Properties), we can disregard the lower-order term of the polynomial, which gives us O(N^2 / 2).

According to the same properties, we can disregard the constant factor, which leaves us with O(N^2).